# Morphism of smooth varieties that induces an isomorphism at the tangent space at a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

This may be quite an elementary question but I can't quite find a proof for this. So assume i have a morphism $f: X \mapsto Y$ where $X,Y$ are smooth affine varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. Furthermore assume there exist points $x,y$ such that $df_x:T_xX \mapsto T_yY$ is an isomorphism. Is it then true that the induced map on the structure sheaves $\mathcal{O}_Y \mapsto f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is injective? I think I can prove this when viewing the spaces as manifolds by invoking the inverse function theorem but would greatly appreciate an algebraic proof.

I should probably add that in the context I'm encountering this both $X,Y$ are equipped with a contracting $\mathbb{C}^*$ action $f$ is equivariant wrt to this action and $x,y$ are the unique fixed points of the action. I am hoping that this extra piece of information is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algebraic reformulation of your statement is the following. Let
$$
\phi \colon (A, \mathfrak{m}) \to (B, \mathfrak{n})
$$
be a morphism of regular local $\mathbb{C}$-rings such that
$$
\phi_1 \colon \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 \to \mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{n}^2
$$
is an isomorphism. Then $\phi$ is injective.

Assume it is not. Let $a \in A$ be an element in the kernel. Then $a \in \mathfrak{m}^k \setminus \mathfrak{m}^{k+1}$ for some $k$ and
$$
\phi_k \colon \mathfrak{m}^k/\mathfrak{m}^{k+1} \to \mathfrak{n}^k / \mathfrak{n}^{k+1}
$$
takes the class of $a$ to zero. But
$$
\mathfrak{m}^k/\mathfrak{m}^{k+1} \cong \operatorname{Sym}^k(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2),
\qquad
\mathfrak{n}^k/\mathfrak{n}^{k+1} \cong \operatorname{Sym}^k(\mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{n}^2),
$$
by the regularity assumption, and $\phi_k = \operatorname{Sym}^k(\phi_1)$, hence it is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Daniel: of course! Now corrected, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear it seems to me that neither the fact we are working over $\mathbb{C}$ and the fact the the variety is smootj are used (Of course smoothness at x and y is used) am I correct to assume these assumptions are not needed?

Comment: Sure, many assumptions can be relaxed.